# Sharing php5-fpm.sock

Tags: php, nginx

I have a web server running NGINX that serves multiple websites. Can I share the same php5-fpm.sock between all the sites?

I am currently doing it for 2 of the sites (one is vbulletin and the other is mediawiki) and have not seen any issues, but I am not sure if this is a recommended best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can, it's normal practice. You would use different sockets if you have security concerns or if you need different PHP configurations.

Of course you could add more sockets/pools to utilize more processes, e.g. CPU count.